# full calendar doesn't display in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fullcalendar

I am trying to create full calendar in web application. But the calendar doesn't display in browser. I don't know what should i do? 
I follow the code in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ and i tray to test it in http://jsfiddle.net and it work.However, When i test the web app, it doesn't give any error only empty whit page in both chrome and explorer . 
hope you know the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example code and results from snippet below. The possible reason you did not get it could be the external library was not included.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.css' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>


<div id='calendar'></div>
```